# can I get parameters from URL in pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Can I use a parameter from Carte's URL in a Job? Something like this:

http://localhost:8080/kettle/startJob/?name=myjob&xml=Y&testvar=filename.txt

I want to do this because I have a job to transform an input file but I want to change that filename dynamically, and creating a new XML file for each file is a bit nonsense.

I've tried many things and I couldn't find a solution :-(

Comment: Did you set this same parameter 'testvar' in your ktr parameters tab ? Seems to be the way to use named parameters with Carte.

Comment: I'll add an answer for that

Answer (score 1):

All named parameters must be declared in the parameters tab of said JOB and KTR to be executed and receive the information passed from the URL parameters.

Comment: I have another issue in the same flow. I have to read the params from the URL (which I am able to do now) and send the same params along with a  URL. I have tried Using REST API but it's not able to ping the URL through carte.